# Converter Switch para IF

Tags: c#, switch

Olá a todos é o seguinte eu tenho este código e precisava de o mudar para `if` em vez de `switch`, como posso fazer isso?

```
switch (theOperator)
{
     case "+":
         total2 = total1 + double.Parse(total3.ToString());
         break;
     case "-":
         total2 = total1 - double.Parse(total3.ToString());
         break;
     case "/":
         total2 = total1 / double.Parse(total3.ToString());
         break;
     case "*":
         total2 = total1 * double.Parse(total3.ToString());
         break;
     default:
         MessageBox.Show("Este simbolo não é reconhecido", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
         break;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou colocar a resposta, mas deixo claro que isto **NÃO É RECOMENDADO**, o `switch` é muito mais legível e faz um melhor uso da memória do que os *statements* `if/else`.

Dito isso, o seguinte bloco:

```
switch (theOperator) {
     case "+":
         total2 = total1 + double.Parse(total3.ToString());
         break;
     case "-":
         total2 = total1 - double.Parse(total3.ToString());
         break;
     case "/":
         total2 = total1 / double.Parse(total3.ToString());
         break;
     case "*":
         total2 = total1 * double.Parse(total3.ToString());
         break;
     default:
         MessageBox.Show("Este simbolo não é reconhecido", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
         break;
}
```

Se transforma em:

```
if (theOperator == "+") {
   total2 = total1 + double.Parse(total3.ToString());
}
else if (theOperator == "-") {
   total2 = total1 - double.Parse(total3.ToString());
}
else if (theOperator == "*") {
   total2 = total1 * double.Parse(total3.ToString());
}
else if (theOperator == "/") {
   total2 = total1 / double.Parse(total3.ToString());
}
else {
   MessageBox.Show("Este simbolo não é reconhecido", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: ok se o switch é melhor vou deixar o switch mas obrigado na mesma pela ajuda

Comment: Por que seria mais legível nesse caso?

Comment: Pelo menos pra mim, eu acho que o switch é um jeito muito mais legível para entender o código, porque voce agrupa todas as verificações em condicionais simples

Answer (score 2):

Pra quem quiser uma opção diferente, que tal?

```
if (theOperator == "+") {
           operacao = soma;
        }
        else if (theOperator == "-") {
           operacao = subtracao;
        }
        else if (theOperator == "*") {
           operacao = multiplicacao;
        }
        else if (theOperator == "/") {
           operacao = divisao;
        }
        else {
          MessageBox.Show("Este simbolo não é reconhecido", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        total2 = operacao(total1,double.Parse(total3.ToString()));
```

A minha pode ser a até menos recomendável, mas pelo menos é mais divertida.
Fazendo uso de funções encapsuladas e expressões lambda.
Eis o código completo:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Calcula("+",1,2);
        Calcula("-",1,2);
        Calcula("*",1,2);
        Calcula("/",1,2);
    }

    public static void Calcula(string theOperator, double total1, double total3)
    {

        double total2 = 0;                          

        //Encapsulo os métodos
        Func<double,double,double> soma = (a,b) => a + b;
        Func<double,double,double> subtracao = (a,b) => a - b;
        Func<double,double,double> multiplicacao = (a,b) => a * b;
        Func<double,double,double> divisao = (a,b) => a / b;


        Func<double,double,double> operacao = null;


        if (theOperator == "+") {
           operacao = soma;
        }
        else if (theOperator == "-") {
           operacao = subtracao;
        }
        else if (theOperator == "*") {
           operacao = multiplicacao;
        }
        else if (theOperator == "/") {
           operacao = divisao;
        }
        else {
          MessageBox.Show("Este simbolo não é reconhecido", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        total2 = operacao(total1,double.Parse(total3.ToString()));  

        Console.WriteLine(total2);

    }   

}
```

Fiz um exemplo compilando em 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/T01SsB